# What can be done to make a javascript function that needs to evaluate an expression safe?

Tags: javascript, function, validation, eval

What can be done to make a javascript function that needs to evaluate an expression safe?  Currently Eval() was replaced with new Function() but I don't think that is safe either.

I'm using veracode to assist with code review - it said "use of eval is dangerous for interpreting user input" which is obvious.  The developer went back and replaced the eval function and is using new Function much to the safe effect. It is very difficult to sanitize javascript input but as a last resort we could using google's Closure library - but is there a safe way of doing what the developer is trying to do? I'm guessing not but javascript isn't my main language so I hope stackoverflow experts can assist.

replacing eval with new function - veracode still complains which makes perfect sense.

```
function evalExpression (expression) {
    if (expression) {
        //Todo: This code needs to be executed in very closed environmet.
        //Eval function security fix
        try {
            return (new Function( 'return (' + expression + ')' )());
        } catch (e) {
            $log.error('Expression eval failed', expression);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: unless you write your own parser, there is nothing safe. The real question is, why is eval being used in the first place?

Comment: `new Function(code)` is just as unsafe as `eval(code)` is

Comment: It’s about context. In which context is the user inputting data and then how is that data going to be used? Is the data going directly to he database? Is the data being used for something else?

Comment: @SF if you're waiting for more feedback, this is it. Until you address the questions you've been asked already, there is nothing further the "stackoverflow experts" can advise, given how broad this question is without any context.

Comment: What are some good mitigation strategies?

Comment: You can create a sandboxed `<iframe>` and run this code in there.

Comment: Ok Thank you everyone - I'll get with the developer and find out some context in how the function is being used. If you have any links I should read up on let me know.

Comment: There are differences between the 2 in the scoping though. If your code is to return raw data and not functions, I think web workers can be a solution too

Answer (score 0):

You can use an expression parser such as [MathJS parser](https://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/parsing.html), [jsep](https://github.com/EricSmekens/jsep) or my [SwanJS](https://github.com/onlabsorg/swan-js).